# What are the options when a question has already been asked and the answers seem not satisfactory?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do if my question has already been asked, but the answers don’t help me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112980/what-should-i-do-if-my-question-has-already-been-asked-but-the-answers-dont-he)

If I'm not the OP but I'm interested about a particular question, what can I do if I consider the answers given are not satisfactory.

If I ask a similar question it can possibly be closed.

From my point of view is like if the question is being "kidnaped".

Comment: [Place a bounty on it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/140951)

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas But the question could be closed before the option for bounties is available.

Comment: If the *original* question is closed, maybe there's a reason for that.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Barber Please see the [comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160272/what-are-the-options-when-a-question-has-already-been-asked-and-the-answers-seem#comment464484_160274) I've left on the answer below.

Comment: It does not appear to be closed.

Comment: @Rosinante ...what not appears to be closed?

Comment: The question. is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

If a question is closed, it means that five stalwart community members (or one moderator, or some combination thereof) decided that it was not an appropriate question.

So the first thing you have to ask yourself is this: 'Do I really have an appropriate question for this site?'

If you do, you now have two choices. You can edit the existing question to be appropriate, and vote to reopen it, or you can create a new question. If the old question was closed, and your new question does not suffer from the problems that caused it to be closed, you are unlikely to have your question closed as a duplicate of it.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47552/what-is-the-time-dilation-for-a-massless-particle), this [answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/27803/16211) given to the question being suggested as "original", and my [comment](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47552/what-is-the-time-dilation-for-a-massless-particle#comment98318_47552). Given that I can't add a comment to that answer, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I see. One question about a photon is closed as a duplicate of another question about a photon. You posted a comment asking about the 'eternal unconscious state' of photons. I'm not a regular at physics, but I can tell you that talking about the psychological state of photons is not going to get you a friendly reception there. And if you can post a comment on the closed question, you can surely post a comment on the open question, if you really want to try to extract further explanation. However, your particular concern is likely to yield silence or scorn.

Comment: Not necessarily, from my point of view the answer says that photons do not experience time, so it has no sense to ask what is the time dilation for a photon. That is why a photon or an inteligent being of light would experience a eternal unconscious state or oblivion.